# VPN into mac osx server from home

Tags: mac-osx, vpn, mac

We have an OSX server running 10.4 in our office. We would like to access the RAID drives externally (eg. from home).

Can anyone detail steps to go through to set this up?

Comment: Does this server have an external IP address or can it be NAT'ed through your firewall?

Comment: It can  be NAT'd.

Answer (score 2):

Just read [the server docs.](http://images.apple.com/server/macosx/docs/Network_Services_Admin_v10.6.pdf) It's explained in detail in there.

I just have a link for the 10.6 version ready, but VPN config is quasi identical in 10.4, just looks a little bit different.

Answer (score 0):

This link will help you: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3104

Comment: Don't just post links, include the relevant sections from the link in your answer.