# VPN into mac osx server from home

Tags: mac-osx, mac, vpn

We have a MacOS X server running 10.4 in our office.  We would like to access the RAID drives externally (e.g., from home).

Can anyone detail the steps to go through to set this up?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VPN into mac osx server from home](http://serverfault.com/questions/242770/vpn-into-mac-osx-server-from-home)

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend OpenVPN -- it's free, highly configurable, and totally compatible with NAT (you can override the default UDP port number and also set it to use TCP {useful if your clients get stuck behind a firewall that blocks all UDP traffic except for DNS}).

For MacOS X clients, there is a port of OpenVPN called TunnelBlick as well, which a few of my clients are using with success.

OpenVPN
  http://www.openvpn.net/

TunnelBlick
  http://code.google.com/p/tunnelblick/

An interesting overview of OpenVPN and TunnelBlick
  http://www.lumbercartel.ca/resources/security.pl#openvpn

After your VPN is functioning correctly, then it is up to you to configure your client computer to connect to your server, which will be just like connecting in an internal network (only a bit slower because you'll be limited to whatever speed your internet access is).  You can use whatever protocols you normally use internally, because OpenVPN's tunnel simply extends your server's network to include your remote client.

Answer (score 0):

I like OpenVPN (use it all the time and it works great) I have really started to love the L2TP VPN built into OS X  works with every device without an extra client.

This should get you started.

http://www.maclive.net/sid/132